# Running Python from C++ (VS2010, compiler v100)

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, crt, msvcr90.dll

I have some code here that we used to use to call a Python script from our (very large) application.  It worked fine when we used `VS2008` (compiler `v90`), which is what the default version of `python27` was compiled with.

In the last year we've upgraded our application to `VS2010`, and I was looking to update the Python-calling dll, thinking it would be a morning's work.  Unfortunately, after wrestling with the linker and missing dlls for ages, most of my colleagues agree that our application and `python27.dll` are using incompatible versions of `Windows CRT`.

I thought it would be simple enough to find a version of `python27.dll` (or indeed another version would be fine) compiled with `VS2010 (v100)` - but I can't.

Is there a way to call a Python script from an application compiled in `VS2010`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer may be: Download the python sources - compile a custom python.dll and link against that.

Comment: I was really hoping that wasn't going to be the answer.  So every other person running Python from C++ is using the same compiler as Python happened to chose?

Comment: @MikeSadler Using Linux makes it easy (I do not care about it), sorry ;-)

Comment: With some reluctance I have to accept this as the correct solution.  For other people's reference:   1) Download the appropriate tarball  2) Find the folder 'PCBuild'   3) Upgrade the pcbuild.sln to the latest version of Visual Studio.  To the credit of the Python authors and MS, this seems to work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. The solution is indeed to build python from the sources. But there is a big drawback: all extra 3rd party python modules pre-build for `Windows` that you download from internet will not work! This is because all of those modules will be prebuild with `VS 2008` and you get again in trouble with incompatible runtimes. The solution is that all such extra modules needs to be again rebuild from sources, but the task is not easy in all cases. The modules are ususally tested in `VS2008` and you get a lot of troubles trying to run them with `VS2010`. I got this mostly with database connectors for `MySQL`, `MSSQL` and others.

Comment: Yes - sorry, I forgot to mention that!  I actually only needed the basic libraries, so I just didn't bother compiling all of the 3rd party libraries.